# How to provide namespace of Kernel to Codeception for a Symfony4 project

Tags: php, symfony, codeception, symfony-3.3, symfony-flex

I'm testing Symfony4 new directory structure with Coception.

Codeception is installed and configured. Because of the end of bundle strategy, I known that an error will occured and here is the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Kernel' not found in `...\my_project\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Module\Symfony.php:146`

Codeception don't find Kernel class, because of its new namespace which is App and not an empty namespace.

Kernel is now in the src directory and declared in the App namespace.

### The new Kernel declaration

<kbd>src/Kernel.php</kbd>

```
namespace App; // <-- the namespace

[...]

class Kernel extends BaseKernel[...]
```

Previously, Kernel was named AppKernel and didn't have namespace:

### The old Kernel declaration

<kbd>app/AppKernel.php</kbd>

```
<?php

//no namespace

[...]

class AppKernel extends Kernel
```

I edited the 265th line of the `Symfony.php` file to change this line which is returning `Kernel`:

`$class = $file->getBasename('.php');`

by this line to return `App\Kernel`:

`$class = 'App\\'.$file->getBasename('.php');`

This modification forces the new namespace of the new structure.

**My functional tests run perfectly**, but I want to avoid modification in vendor file.

How can I force the App namespace without this *hack*? It seems there is no parameter to do it, but can I encapsulate codeception in the app namespace or find a hack to put it in my files, not in the vendor file?

Comment: `class_alias('App\Kernel', 'AppKernel');` isn't enough?

Comment: Nice idea, but it doesn't work. I tried:
I tried too : `class_alias('App\Kernel', 'Kernel');` but I handle this error : `Cannot declare class App\Kernel, because the name is already in use `

Comment: Oh sorry ! It works! I put it in two `bootstrap.php` file (in the tests\functional and the tests directory) If I put it only in one file, it works better of course

Comment: If you would like to write your answer, I will validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an alias for the Kernel class:

```
   class_alias('App\Kernel', 'Kernel');
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue in Codeception https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/4695. Basically Codeception only allows certain Symfony Kernel names:

```
# codeception/src/Codeception/Module/Symfony.php:287

$possibleKernelClasses = [
    'AppKernel', // Symfony Standard
    'App\Kernel', // Symfony Flex
];
```

The workaround, for now, would be to use `class_alias('MyNamespace\Kernel', 'App\Kernel');` as was noted by @Federkun.